# Como passar por todo o laço

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Estou com um pequeno problema para que todo o `radio` seja preenchido com tudo o que está no array de acordo.

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte, exemplo:

```
1 - Quanto é 1+1?
A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
E) 5

2 - Quanto é 2+2?
A) 5
B) 4
C) 10
D) 20
E) 70
```

As alternativas estão salvas no array, e o laço não está montando dessa forma, ele não varre todo o array, ele fica repetindo em todas as questões as 5 primeiras posições aí fica assim.

```
1 - Quanto é 1+1?
A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
E) 5

2 - Quanto é 2+2?
A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
E) 5
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".iniciar").click(function(){

    var disciplina = $('#disciplinaProfessor').val();
    var unidade = $('#unidade').val();
    var liberada = 'L';

    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",  
      url: "../RealizaProvaServlet",  
      dataType: 'json', 
      data: 'disciplina='+disciplina+'&unidade='+unidade+'&liberada='+liberada, 
      success: function(data) {  

          var perguntas = [ { "Quanto é 1 + 1?", "Quanto é 1 + 2", "Quanto e 1+3"} ]
          var alternativas = [ { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" ] } ]


          for (var i = 0; i < data.perguntas.length; i++) {
              perguntas.push(data.perguntas[i]);
        }

          for (var i = 0; i < data.alternativas.length; i++) {
              alternativas.push(data.alternativas[i]);
        }


          var qntCadaPergunta = 5;
          var prova = '';
          var questoes = '';
          var valor = 6.0;
          var letras = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];


          for (var i = 0; i < alternativas.length && i < qntCadaPergunta; i++) {

              questoes += ''+letras[i]+")"+"<br />"+'<input type="radio" name="alternativa" value= "teste"> '+alternativas[i]+'</input>'+'<br /><br /><br />';

  }

          for (var j = 0; j < perguntas.length; j++) {

              prova += '<br /><input id="pergunta" style = "border: 0 none;" disabled="disabled" type="text" name="pergunta" value="' + perguntas[j] +
              '"/><br /><br /><input type="text" id="valorQuestao" style = "border: 0 none;" disabled="disabled" value="'+valor+'"/><br /> <br /> <br />'+questoes;

          }




          document.getElementById("alternativas").innerHTML = questoes;
          document.getElementById("perguntas").innerHTML = prova;

    },

        }); 

    return false;

});
});
```

*Servlet* onde eu busco as perguntas e alternativas do banco:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int disciplina = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("disciplina"));
    int unidade = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("unidade"));
    String provaLiberada = request.getParameter("liberada");

    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();  
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


    try {


        // ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨ PEGA O ULTIMO VALOR DA PROVA ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
                    PreparedStatement stmtVerifica = Conexao.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                            "SELECT * FROM prova where cod_disciplina ='"+ disciplina + "' and unidade ='"+ unidade + "' and liberada ='"+ provaLiberada + "';");

                    ResultSet rsVerifica = stmtVerifica.executeQuery();

                    while (rsVerifica.next()) {
                        int codigo_prova_banco = rsVerifica.getInt("cod_prova");
                        this.cod_prova = codigo_prova_banco;
                        this.trazer = true;

                    }
        // ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨ PEGA O ULTIMO VALOR DA PROVA ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨



        if(this.trazer == true){

 // ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨ TRAS AS QUESTÕES DA PROVA ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
            PreparedStatement stmtPerguntas = Conexao.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT DISTINCT PERGUNTA FROM questao where cod_prova ='"+ this.cod_prova + "';");

            ResultSet rsPerguntas = stmtPerguntas.executeQuery();

            while (rsPerguntas.next()) {

                this.perguntas.add(rsPerguntas.getString("pergunta"));
            }



            PreparedStatement stmtAlternativas = Conexao.getConnection().prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT ALTERNATIVA FROM questao where cod_prova ='"+ this.cod_prova + "';");

            ResultSet rsAlternativas = stmtAlternativas.executeQuery();

            while (rsAlternativas.next()) {

                this.alternativa.add(rsAlternativas.getString("alternativa"));
            }


// ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨ TRAS AS QUESTÕES DA PROVA ¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨



        }

         json.put("perguntas", this.perguntas);  
         json.put("alternativas", this.alternativa);  
         out.print(json);

         json.remove("perguntas");
         json.remove("alternativas");


         this.perguntas.removeAll(perguntas);
         this.alternativa.removeAll(alternativa);
         this.trazer = false;

         out.close();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

E a JSP onde são setados os campos dinâmicos:

```
<form id="realizarProva">
    <div id="perguntas">
        <div id="alternativas"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Podes colocar também o código dessa variável  `data`? O HTML é todo gerado por JS?

Comment: `perguntas` e `alternativas` estão vazias? como estás a preencher esses dados?

Comment: Ai esta a JSP, a JS, e a Servlet

Comment: Seria melhor se você colocasse o resultado do seu `JSON`.

Comment: O que você acha de mudar a estrutura desse `JSON`? Acho que poderia ficar mais legível se você escrevesse assim:

`[ { "pergunta": "Quanto é 1 + 1?", "alternativas": [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ] } ]`

Comment: Coloquei o Array com os resultados, o problema esta e em varrer esses arrays, pois o laço não passa nas outras alternativas, so pega as primeiras posições